# conversion from radian to degree [python 2]

Tags: math, trigonometry, python-2.x

What is wrong with following piece of code

```
import math
n = input ()
l = int(round((n*180)/math.pi))
print l
```

Gives wrong answer.
if n = 0.707106781187, then it gives l = 41. It should be 45.

Comment: I think you are getting the right answer. What you probably thinking of is that sin(45°) = 1/sqrt(2). The equivalent of 45° in radians is 0.7853981633974483.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mixed up degrees and gradians. A corner of 45 gradians is equal to about 41 degrees, a corner of 50 gradians is exactly 45 degrees. The program itself is correct. The entered input value for 45 degrees should be ‪0.785398‬, which is pi divided by 4.

More about degrees, radians and gradians can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian